# Highchart pie-basic

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

Good day guys. So I've got some kind of problem of my highcharts pie, where I've got only two items/legends where 1995 and 1996. I've got a data in 1995 where there are 2 and 1996 is 0.

It displays the pie chart, but the problem is that it's wrong in percentage. As you can see in the image below it show both the 1995 and 1996.

The 1995 should be in 100% and not in 10% because i've got only two items, the 1996 is correct however because i've got no data. [image]

Here is my php code

```
<?php 
    require '/db/database_configuration.php';

    $_1995 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM `tblalumni` WHERE yeargrad LIKE '1995' and alum_status LIKE 2");
    $_1996 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM `tblalumni` WHERE yeargrad LIKE '1996' and alum_status LIKE 2");

    $_1995 = mysqli_fetch_array($_1995);
    $_1996 = mysqli_fetch_array($_1996);

    // displays zero if none
    if (empty($_1995['Total'])) { $_1995 = '0'; } else { $_1995 = $_1995['Total'];}
    if (empty($_1996['Total'])) { $_1996 = '0'; } else { $_1996 = $_1996['Total'];}


    $ans_1995 = '1995';
    $ans_1996 = '1996';


    $Data95 = $_1995;
    $Data96 = $_1996;


?>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: <?php echo json_encode($ans_1995); ?>,
            y: [<?php echo $Data95; ?>]
        }, {
            name: <?php echo json_encode($ans_1996); ?>,
            y: [<?php echo $Data96; ?>]
        }]
    }]
});
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: <?php echo json_encode($ans_1995); ?>,
        y: [<?php echo $Data95; ?>]
    }, {
        name: <?php echo json_encode($ans_1996); ?>,
        y: [<?php echo $Data96; ?>]
    }]
}]
```

to

```
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: <?php echo json_encode($ans_1995); ?>,
        y: <?php echo $Data95; ?>
    }, {
        name: <?php echo json_encode($ans_1996); ?>,
        y: <?php echo $Data96; ?>
    }]
}]
```

Just remove brackets.. HAHAHAH